# SharpDX : edit shader fx file while application is running

Tags: visual-studio, directx-11, sharpdx

Is there an easy way to edit a shader fx file while the application is running to see the changes?

Right now I have to recompile it by hand with DirectX11-net40\tkfxc.exe and restart my whole application to see the changes.

Comment: You need to build shader replacement functionality into your application. First, you must specify which shader has to be replaced (build a directory watcher for edited files and issue an event whenever a shader file has been changed). Then you can load the source code in your application and compile it using `D3DCompile()` (though I don't know if that's available in SharpDX (deamn I can't help but pronouncing that as "SharpDicks"!)). When the code is compiled, you simply create a new shader using `device.CreateXXXShader()` and replace the refrence to old shader interface with the new one.

Comment: D3DCompile in sharpdx is of course available : ShaderBytecode.Compile is the relevant function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using SharpDX Toolkit otherwise you need to develop this on your side. If you are compiling your project as it is used in SharpDX samples (not using tkfxc.exe) but by setting the correct "ToolkitFxc" action on your shader and using the EffectCompilerSystem in your code, as shown in the sample [CustomEffect](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX-Samples/blob/master/Toolkit/Common/CustomEffect/CustomEffectGame.cs#L56), this should work directly.